# form not submitting selected value when updated via ajax (rails & jquery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form that has several drop downs, when one is chosen, it updates another. When I submit this form, the values of the drop downs that are updated via ajax dont get submitted. When I look at the form using firebug after its been updated, it looks good.

Here is my code

```
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

  $j(document).ready(
function(){
   $j('#source_credential_list').change(function(){
          var source_credential = $j("#source_credential").val();
         $j.post("/retrieved_data_records/keys_for_source_credential", {"source_credential":source_credential}, function(result) {
         });
         });
}
```

```
 <% form_tag  '/retrieved_data_records', :method => :get do %>

      <tr>
     <td>
        <b> Source Credentials</b>
        </td>
         <td>
               <span id="source_credential_list">
                  <%= render :partial => 'source_credential_list' %>
               </span>
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <b>Source Keys</b>
     </td>
    <td>
       <span id="source_key_list">
           <%= render :partial => 'source_key_list' %>
       </span>

     </td>
  </tr>
<div id="filtersButton"><td><%=submit_tag 'Filter'%></td></div>
```

The source_key_list partial:

```
 <%=select_tag :filter_source_key, options_from_collection_for_select(@all_source_keys, 'key_name', 'display_fancy_name', @selected_key.key_name)%>
```

Server side keys_for_source_credential returns:

```
 $j("#source_key_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'source_credential_key_list')) %>");
```

source_credential_key_list parital:

```
 <%=select_tag :filter_source_key, options_from_collection_for_select(@all_credential_keys.sort, 'key_name', 'display_fancy_name')%>
```

On my server the drop down value is not submitted. I guess I could manually post my drop down selection along with the form post, but it seems like it should be working...Im sure I am doing something dumb.

any ideas?

thanks
Joel

Comment: Posting the actual, generated HTML and **not** the code that generates it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was I had a table started before my form and ended after my form, moving the table start and end inside the form fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't use val, use text instead

```
 $j("#source_credential").text();
```

Comment: The element with ID `source_credential` isn't even in the HTML provided, so there's no way to know what kind of element it is. I assume that it's supposed to be the drop down list that's mentioned in the question, though.

Comment: the ajax part works fine, its the form submit that is not working right, for some reason when I replace a span with an element with the same id, it seems to form doesnt know to submit it along with the orig elements of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem that form not submitting my selected value in select elecment.

I resolved by changing 'id' to 'name'.